# Facing issues while running CI scripts for Flutter application

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm encountering difficulty describing the error I'm facing—it's quite lengthy. The problem arises when attempting to run a GitHub workflow with my custom CI scripts for GitHub releases. You can access the workflow [here](https://github.com/KeroJohn97/alt_bangumi/actions/runs/7469819901/job/20327884525). The workflow is titled 'Draft Github Release' and there's a job named 'Create Android build'. The error occurs during the execution of the command 'flutter build -v apk --release'. Interestingly, the same command works without issues on my local machine, but it seems to get stuck in the workflow.

Additionally, there's another issue in a different job: 'Create Linux build'. The issue is connected to the GitHub Actions step named 'Add packaged build to release draft', specifically involving the package 'upload-release-asset', and the error message indicates 'Validation failed. Unfortunately, I'm not certain about the cause of the failure. It's worth noting that these scripts have run successfully in previous workflows. As someone not well-versed in CI/CD and GitHub actions, I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Finally, here's a reference I'm using to build up my CI scripts: https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/main/.github/workflows/release_draft_github_release.yml